# Protobufjs - creating interface for google.protobuf.FieldOptions proto

Tags: typescript, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobufjs

I'm trying to run this command:

```
pbjs -t json-module -w commonjs -o json-module.js ../common/protobuf/*.proto
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: unresolvable extensions: 'extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions' in ..., 'extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions' in ...
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your question would benefit from providing more details that would help us help you: what version of `pbjs` are you using? What is `/common/protobuf/*.proto`? The error suggests that these protos reference `google.protobuf.FieldOptions` which is defined in [`descriptor.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto) and usually shipped with tooling.